How do I deal with error truncating #REF with spark.read
I am trying to read an excel file with spark.read.format, and even using PERMISSIVE mode, its truncating the records that contains #REF! in any column
Can anyone please help me on that?

schema = StructType([\
        StructField('Col1', DateType(), True), \ <----------THIS COLUMN HAS #REF
        StructField('Col2', DateType(), True), \
        StructField('Col3', StringType(), True)])

test = (
                            spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
                            .option("header", header_option)
                            .option("parseMode", "PERMISSIVE")
                            .option("keepUndefinedRows", True)
                            .option("useNullForErrorCells", True)
                            .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", True)
                            .option("setErrorCellsToFallbackValues", "true")
                            .option("maxRowsInMemory", 1000)
                            .option("useNullForErrorCells", True)
                            .option("dataAddress", "Test!A1:C200")
                            .schema(schema)
                            .load("File.xlsx")

I need to ingest these records, not truncate it

fix the problem in the Excel source. A #Ref! error in Excel means there's a broken cell reference in a formula, so this cell will not have the correct value, anyway.

So, there is no way of ingesting the excel file just replacing the error for "Null", for example?

I can only talk to the Excel side. I don't know the other technologies.
